# How do you put multiple circles in a grid ?

Tags: python-3.x

i have been able to create circles in a  5 by 5. I am stuck on putting circles in a 10 X 10 grid. How do i put the circles inside a 10X10 grid using python 3 synax?

here is my current code;

Thank you :)

```
centrex = 5
centrey = 5
colour1 = "red"
colour2 = "white"


for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        circle = Circle(Point(centrex,centrey),5)
        circle.setFill(colour2)
        circle.setOutline(colour2)
        circle.draw(win)
        centrex+=10
    centrex=5
    centrey+=10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the `for` loops run through a larger range. Then define the 4 different colours you want to use for the four sectors in the grid, and use those in the inner loop body:

```
centrex = 5
centrey = 5
fillcolours = [["red",   "blue"], 
               ["green", "grey"]]
bordercolour = "white"
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        fillcolour = fillcolours[i // 5][j // 5]
        circle = Circle(Point(centrex,centrey),5)
        circle.setFill(fillcolour)
        circle.setOutline(bordercolour)
        circle.draw(win)
        centrex+=10
    centrex=5
    centrey+=10
```

Comment: thank you for your response, what i am trying to do is to create the 5x5 circles and have them in a 10 X 10. so 5X5 cirles inside a 10 x 10 grid. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: so what I am trying to do is to draw grid within a grid. for example, the 5X5 circles are 25 circles in a section of a grid. so i make a 10 X 10 big grid and put 5 X 5 of small circle grids inside it, the whole colour is at the end I want to colour the circles with different colours. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: so i would like to create something like this. https://www.google.com/search?q=circle+grids&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=PUGrX0FrIOr2nM%253A%252CLdeJpqUmNRc1QM%252C_&usg=AI4_-kRnuuPIAwHpKsjei6uS0Iq0CFDuxQ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijis-k8LjfAhXTTRUIHZq_Dv4Q9QEwBXoECAQQDg#imgrc=PUGrX0FrIOr2nM:

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=circle+grids&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=PUGrX0FrIOr2nM%253A%252CLdeJpqUmNRc1QM%252C_&usg=AI4_-kRnuuPIAwHpKsjei6uS0Iq0CFDuxQ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijis-k8LjfAhXTTRUIHZq_Dv4Q9QEwBXoECAQQDg#imgrc=06YuoDfW3RcWxM:

Comment: That link for an image from google for an example i would like tio create

Comment: so from that example, we can see the 2 X 2 grid circles inside the 4 X 4 big grid size.

Comment: no i dont want to add the lines for the time being. For example from my original code i was able to create a 5 by 5 circles. However i want create those 5 by 5 circles in a bigger grid. That what i would want to do using nested for loops meaning which means i need to increament the positions of the next positions of the 5 by 5 circles. This is where i am stuck at

Comment: so the circles in the first  5 X 5 section would have different colours to the circles in the second section of the 5x 5 and so on

Comment: Updated answer after it became clear you want to distinguish sections of the grid by using a different colour. I am rereading your question, and I don't see any reference to that. How did you expect anyone to understand that?